# ora-27102 out of memory windows

Tags: oracle

I run oracle 11.2 on server 2016 with 64 gb RAM.
When I increase memory_max_target to 8 gb, and startup after shutdown it shows above error.
i.e. ora-27102 out of memory windows
About 58GB RAM is free on machine.
Regards
M Akbar Khan

Comment: the error message is really "ora-27102 out of memory windows"? I only found "ora-27102 out of memory" in the [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ERRMG/ORA-24280.htm#ERRMG-GUID-7B2814DB-F946-4EB1-80B5-219B256E90C0). Did you already check the manual for this error?  What is the description of this error?

Answer (score -1):

This might help: https://doyensys.com/blogs/ora-27102-out-of-memory-startup/

My summary: remove sga_target and sga_max_size. Set memory_max_target and memory_target both to 8G.

Otherwise look at your alert log and see what errors you get when it starts up. There should be more detail there.

Bobby

Comment: that is not a good advise. there may be a reason to use sga_target instead of memory_target, e.g. on linux if you use huge_pages. it is also not useful to reference to an article where the author does not show any deeper insight into the problem.

Comment: The post says "windows" and "server 2016" so I assume that it is not Linux.